# Why does BIOS use battery-backed memory instead of storing settings in EEPROM?

Tags: bios

When you take out the motherboard battery, PC forgets its BIOS settings. At the same time, BIOS is stored on an EEPROM and can be easily upgraded with no extra tooling. Why doesn't BIOS use this memory to store the settings without the use of a battery?

Comment: Have you researched the relative costs involved?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin what kind of costs?

Comment: Start with manufacturing costs... Then, consider the cost of supporting circuitry, which may be different for the two types of chips.

Comment: *When you take out the motherboard battery, PC forgets its BIOS settings.* The time needed to loose this settings vary (on present m/b) from approx. 15 min to a lot of months depending by CMOS chip type. The only immediately effect of battery remove is clock stop. *Why doesn't BIOS use this memory to store the settings without the use of a battery?* BIOS use EEPROM memory to store the default settings - it's enough. One more - if we allow BIOS to store settings in EEPROM the risk of its content damage will increase.

Comment: Have you considered that if you misconfigure the bios and the system would not boot anymore, you can trash the pc? Now you can just reset the bios by removing the battery.

Answer (score 6):

While it can store *settings* in an EEPROM what should it do about the time?

Timekeeping still needs a long-term backup solution and you cannot just say "well you can just get the time off the internet" because in a lot of situations you can't. Some machines need to be air-gapped and cannot be connected to the internet, yet they still need reasonably accurate timekeeping otherwise *everything* on that machine will have happened on the 1st of January 1970.

Supercapacitors and Lithium polymer batteries are expensive compared to one of the most common batteries on the planet and we already have a good solution to keep the clock running for several years without interference.

So. We have to keep the clock running, and it needs a tiny amount of memory as well. There is one question that arises:

**Given that we already have a battery backed memory that is necessary to the operation of the system, does it make sense to introduce *yet another* memory device just to store basic settings that are already "safe" so long as you replace the battery quickly enough?**

I'm pretty sure a lot of UEFI systems probably do store settings in EEPROM anyway these days.

---

As mentioned by others there is also the matter that a great many of the settings stored in this area are quite capable of rendering a system completely unusable.

As an example it stores settings such as forced memory timings, CPU overclocking, CPU voltage and other low level settings that get applied as the system boots.

Without a quick and simple way to erase those settings, preferably while the system is shut down to reduce chances of damage, then we could easily get into a state where the system is completely unusable and could cause more damage to itself simply by being powered on.

Having an easy way to reset the settings, by removing the battery or shorting the battery jumper, gives you a quick and above all *safe* way to restore the system to its failsafe defaults.

An EEPROM would mean having to have some extra hardware and code that detected a switch being pressed on start-up and restored some "known good" settings.  There's a lot more to it that it sounds and doing it at an early stage in the system boot means a lot of extra logic in the hardware and software to deal with it. Erasing an EEPROM isn't actually *that* easy and to do so the BIOS would have a lot of work to do.

It's much simpler to have a battery that, when removed, simply clears all the settings for you.

Comment: I suspect it was also retained because removing a battery is dead simple for intentionally resetting all settings...

Comment: @grawity that's a very good point that I had ignored in my focus on the cost based implications of adding hardware when it isn't needed. Updated.

Comment: Another point worth noting, EEPROM's are write limited (usually only about a thousand write cycles per byte), battery-backed RAM is not.  Modern systems however usually use flash memory, and not an EEPROM's or RAM for storing settings, (best of both worlds, persistent without the battery, but has way more write cycles than an EEPROM), and only need the battery for the RTC.

Answer (score 1):

It is because in the early years, BIOS is stored in ROM, not EEPROM. Data within these chips cannot be rewritten (firmware updates means swapping chips), so settings must be stored in a separate chip that's rewrite-able. As others have stated, we can minimize hardware cost and complexity by simply reusing the battery-powered nonvolatile BIOS memory (aka CMOS) which is already being used to track the system time.

The industry then moved to EPROM, which is rewrite-able after being erased through exposure to UV light. Obviously, such chips are still unsuitable for storing settings.

The industry eventually settled upon EEPROM which can be rewritten programmatically, and it is certainly possible to store the settings there. However as Mokubai stated, storing settings in the CMOS allows users to easily reset the settings in case they messed it up. In addition, the BIOS code for reading/writing settings from/to CMOS has been in use for many years and is well-tested. Thus there isn't much incentive for OEMs to revamp the implementation to switch to EEPROM.

Nevertheless, modern UEFI firmware do store certain settings/configuration in EEPROM aka flash aka NVRAM. e.g. boot entries, boot order, and secure boot keys. These aren't stored in CMOS because:

1. Unlike settings such as memory timings, you can still boot to the firmware set up menu if you mess them up. You can then use the menu to restore the settings.
2. For security, secure boot maintains a list of hashes/certificates of malicious/vulnerable boot components that are blocked from execution, and a similar list for good components that are allowed to execute. The first list is called dbx, and the second is called db. Both fall under the category of secure boot keys. If they were stored in CMOS, the keys would be lost when the battery runs out and the user reboots the computer.
3. CMOS has limited capacity. It's easy to increase it, but more memory cells means greater battery drain to maintain the data.